# Lock my current IP address

Tags: networking, ip-address

How can i lock my current IP address?

the LAN IP address is the 192.********. I know that, but i want to lock up my IP address which i found on the http://whatismyipaddress.com/, which is something like this 115.*********

because right now my client are using my IP address to give me the access to their server and my IP address keep on changing everytime i restart my router (because i need to)

Help please help!

Comment: Contact your ISP.

Answer (score 14):

You need to ask your ISP for a static IP address.
They are likely to charge extra for it.

Alternatively, you could use a dynamic DNS provider, such as [No-IP](http://no-ip.com), which will give you a domain name that always resolves to your IP address.

Comment: The problem is that most programs use *reverse* DNS for checking the access list, and changing it requires a static address too.

Comment: The chances are virtually nil that he needs to worry about a PTR record. It is almost certainly that the company's firewall just restricts connections to a specific IP. I have never heard of a firewall checking a PTR record (reverse DNS) in this case.

Comment: PTR records are typically only necessary for mail servers.